# How did Jane became worthy of holding Thor's hammer?

Tags: marvel, comics, thor-marvel

In the comics, Jane became the new Thor, but how did she become worthy of holding Mjolnir?

Comment: What can I say, I just did! ;)

Comment: I’ve seen other questions suggesting that Odin is the one who determines who is worthy of “the power of Thor.”

Comment: @JaneS but why did Odin chose you ?? ;)